# flutter: My list keeps growing when I hot reload or navigate back to that page

Tags: flutter, firebase

When I navigate back from another screen to this or hotreload, my listview keeps growing. I am fetching content from cloud storage. How could I solve this? I have tried working with initState but no progress.

Here is the code to that screen (Semester screen):

```
class _SemesterState extends State<Semester> {

  late Future<List<String>> courses;
  Future<List<FirebaseFolder>>? listResult;
  Future<List<String>> getFolders() async {
    final storageRef = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(widget.value);
    final listResult = await storageRef.listAll();
    for (var prefix in listResult.prefixes) {
      courses.add(prefix.name); // here is where the error is... I think 
 //you can't use .add on Future List..
    }
    return courses;
  }
```

Is there a way to  add contents to list of type future?
Here is my widget tree:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Semester", style: kTitleStyle),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: courses,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return const Center(
                child: spinkitLines,
              );
            default:
              return Column(
                children: [
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 20.0,
                  ),
                  const Center(
                    child: Text(
                      'Tap to choose course',
                      style: kPlaceholderStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    height: 30.0,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: courses.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () {
                                // on tap operations
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                height: 80,
                                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                  // some beautiful decorations
                                    ),
                                ),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      courses[index],
                                      style: kCardTitleStyle,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                 ....
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `getFolders()` is called in your `build` method, so, whenever the `build` rebuilds itself, more data is added to your list `courses`.

To fix this, create an *instance* of your `Future`, and in the `initState` initialize it. Then, in your `FutureBuilder()` use the created instance as the `future`. Here is a simplified example:

```dart
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  late Future<List<String>> coursesFuture;

  Future<List<String>> getCourses() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    return ['Dart', 'Flutter'];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: coursesFuture,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text('${snapshot.data}');
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
        } else {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    coursesFuture = getCourses();
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

Since I don't have actual access to your Firebase collection, you'll have to refactor this to suit your needs.

I recommend that you watch [this YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pp3zoNDGZUI) video on how to create a `FutureBuilder()` the correct way. He actually explains your problem at 1:55 in the video.

Comment: So i have done as you have said, now i can't use the ".add(prefix.name)" since it says its add is not of type future. Any help on how to add those string values to a Future list.

Comment: @KevinhectorNgetich Can you edit your question to show what error you're getting?

Comment: please follow this post so you can see the edit..was trying to edit but the lights went off. Not sure when it comes back but when it does i will edit it.